# What is the best way to ground a whip antenna in a hotel room?

Tags: antenna, hf, grounding, portable

We have a 102" CB whip antenna cut for 10 meters. We're staying in a hotel and trying to figure out the best way to ground this antenna. Right now we're using a pile of wires on the floor, but we're not getting many contacts and this doesn't seem like a very good ground. Is it safe to ground to the air conditioner's metal frame, or to the ground prong of an electrical outlet? Something that doesn't involve wires on the floor would be ideal.

Normally we use this antenna mounted to a vehicle; in that case, the vehicle acts as the ground. In the hotel room, of course, we can't do that.

Should we be using a balun?

Comment: How is your transmitter grounded?

Comment: @Gil it's a mobile transceiver with no ground connection other than the negative line on the power input.

Comment: Just thinking, I have a SWAG can you use an alligator clip to connect to the metal window frame? RF I think will couple through the anodizing on the metal. You may have to orient the antenna horizontal so the signal will go through the frame. If the bed frame is metal that may work. When you try this be sure you have a SWR meter to be sure you stay in the radios tolerance.

Comment: @Gil that's a good idea, so basically the antenna would radiate through its ground? The bed frame in that particular hotel was not metal, but that's a good idea for ones where it is.

Comment: Should I post it as an answer?